# Creating a new factor variable based off the levels of an old one in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have an initial variable `payfreq` which takes values such as "Weekly", "Monthly", or "Annual". I converted it to a factor variable (for efficient storage) with:

```
wage_data <- mutate(wage_data, payfreq=factor(payfreq)
```

But some observations have missing `payfreq` and I want to impute the pay frequency using the number of days between pay. I do:

```
mutate(imp_payfreq = case_when(
      between(days, 6, 8) ~ "Weekly",
      between(days, 28, 32) ~ "Monthly",
      between(days, 362, 368) ~ "Annual",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_)
)
```

Then I build the final variable like:

```
mutate(final_payfreq=ifelse(is.na(payfreq), imp_payfreq, payfreq)
```

The issue I am having is that I cannot figure out how to make `final_payfreq` use the same levels and labels as the initial `payfreq` variable. In fact, if I enter the order of "Weekly", "Annual", etc differently in `final_payfreq` but use `factor(final_payfreq, levels=levels(wage_data$payfreq)` it will incorrectly assign weekly data as annual, etc.

Is there a concise way to build the `final_payfreq` variable so that it respects the levels and labels of the `payfreq` variable?

Comment: Please make a sample of data available so that others can test the codes.  Your problem could be due to `payfreq` is a factor whereas `imp_payfreq` is character. You can try not to convert `payfreq` to factor at the begining.  Do the conversion only after you have `final_payfreq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @nyk, don't convert `payfreq` to `factor` initially. Perform the transformation that you want to do and finally convert both `final_payfreq` and `payfreq` to factor.

```
library(dplyr)

wage_data %>%
  mutate(imp_payfreq = case_when(
    between(days, 6, 8) ~ "Weekly",
    between(days, 28, 32) ~ "Monthly",
    between(days, 362, 368) ~ "Annual",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_), 
    final_payfreq=ifelse(is.na(payfreq), imp_payfreq, payfreq), 
    across(c(final_payfreq, payfreq), factor, c('Weekly', 'Monthly','Annual'))) -> result

result
```

---

To correct OP's code we can do :

```
wage_data %>%
  mutate(final_payfreq = ifelse(is.na(payfreq), 
                         factor(imp_payfreq, levels(payfreq)), payfreq)
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks Ronak. I knew that was a solution, but my logic for converting it to a factor up front is to save storage space. But it sounds like that is going to create more problems than it solves.

Comment: @BennyGoldman You can still do what you were trying to do, see edit in my answer. Usually it is better if you provide an example data for us to test our answer. It is difficult to help without data.

Comment: Oh great! That looks like it will do what I need. Thanks so much

Comment: One final question Ronak. I noticed if I run the above code the variable final_payfreq that gets created is an integer, not a factor variable. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide an example data for me to test this?